# Where do recursive types fit in the lambda cube?

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus

A way to extend the simply-typed lambda-calculus $\lambda_\to$ is to consider recursive types of the form $\mu\alpha.\tau$ (see for example [http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~iosif/LogicAutomata07/type-systems-slides.pdf](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/%7Eiosif/LogicAutomata07/type-systems-slides.pdf)). The type of lists of integers would be $\mu\tau.Unit+Int\times\tau$.

Does this correspond to one of three directions in the lambda cube? If not, what would be the corresponding extension to propositional logic?

Comment: Is your incentive to have a typed lambda calculus that allows recursion?